# Why does using my SELF-JOIN gives me error?

Tags: sql, self-join

```
select 1.jmeno, 1.nadr
from zam as 1,
    zam as 2
where 1.nadr = 2.nadr
group by 1.jmeno, 1.nadr;
```

Comment: (1) Show your error in the question.  (2) Do not use numbers as table aliases.  (3) **Use explicit `JOIN` syntax!!!**

Comment: Numbers aren't valid identifiers. Use `z1` and `z2` instead.

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY, since no aggregate functions are involved.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your alias name of the tables

```
select a1.jmeno, a1.nadr
from zam as a1 join
    zam as a2
on a1.nadr = a2.nadr
group by a1.jmeno, a1.nadr
```

Answer (score 0):

use alias name by starting with letter and use explicit join not coma separated join

```
select t1.jmeno, t1.nadr
from zam as t1 join  zam as t2
on t1.nadr = t2.nadr
```

as there is no aggregation in your query so i removed group by instead that you could use `distinct`